# Can't insert hebrew language values in vtiger database

Tags: database, structure, collation, vtiger

I want to add hebrew language values to vtiger database.But it shows some questionmarks '????' .I was check the table structure and found the `collation` field is `"latin1_swedish_ci "`.I want to change the `collation` field to `utf8_unicode_ci`.If I change it in manually , is it make any problem in all site and upgradation of vtiger?How can I change the table structure of vtiger?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change it in all of the language files too. I did not succeed yet, just get question marks.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a database in mysql you should select utf8_general_ci and then you should install vtiger crm all the tables will be in utf8 format and you shouldn't have a problem with your languages.